# Magento 2.3.4: Unable to change category products position

Tags: magento2.3

I try to change the position for category products.

In admin, each position is set but in the frontend, nothing changes. Even after clear/flush cache and reindexing.

Do you know how and in which file makes this change programmatically to get product collection sort by product position set in the category section?

Can you please give me the file name and path and solution were to achieve this issue?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Do you have a cache host like varnish cache?

Comment: No, the host do not have any cache.